# How to implement cue-stick animation for a pool game?

Tags: mathematics, animation

Hello I am developing a Pool game, and I've been scratching my head about what formula is needed to implement an animation for the cue stick.

The animation of the cue stick should look as if it's being pulled back, as the user starts to change the amount of power that he/she would like to apply to the ball.

Comment: So, what have you tried?

Comment: Well I was looking at taking the length of the cue stick and finding other points that lie towards the center of the cue stick and easing it towards one of the points outside of the cue stick area, only issue Im really having is letting the cue stick know in wich direction it is turned so it gets pulled back in the correct direction

Comment: If your cue-stick is pointing towards the ball, why do you need to change its direction when pulling it back? Also, is this 2D or 3D?

Comment: 2D, the direction of the stick is changed by the user. The user can rotate the stick around a point that lies at the center of the cue ball to change the direction.

Comment: Ok, so why do you need to know the direction to pull back the cue-stick? You wrote: "*only issue Im really having is letting the cue stick know in wich direction it is turned*". If you have the direction already, why is there a problem?

Comment: Glad you figured it out :). Please consider adding your solution as an answer (and later accept that answer), so that other people with a similar problem can find the solution here.

Answer (score 0):

In pseudo code, and not very pleasant animation, it could be done like this:
I don't really know what you mean by "Animation" I assumed it was the cue moving back depending on the power desired.

```
vector2f starting_position; // Not a local variable, a member variable

mouse_state mouse = get_mouse(); 

// This checks to see if the right button is down
// it is mutually exclusive with the pulling back of the cue
if (mouse.right_button.state == button_state.DOWN && !cue.pulling_back) 
{
    cue.pulling_back = true;
    starting_position = cue.position; // store the initial position of the cue
}

// This will move the cue's position back depending on the 
// axis and junk
if (cue.pulling_back)
{
    // figure out the change in y 
    // or the respected axis of your choice
    cue.position += mouse.position;
    vector2f change = calculate_change(cue.position, starting_position);
    // power modifed based on change
    cue.power = change * (constants);
}

if (previous_mouse.right_button.state == button_state.DOWN && mouse.right_button.state == button_state.UP
    && cue.pulling_back)
{

    if (starting_position != cue.position)
    {
        // reset the cue position and fire ball using cue's power, etc
    }
cue.pulling_back = false;
}

previous_mouse = mouse;
```